# .NET Core interop, Marshal.FreeHGlobal crashes program

Tags: .net, memory-management, .net-core

Consider the following method that I `DllImport` into .NET `IntPtr`.

```
void* getenv()
{
    return malloc(10);
}
```

If I perform a `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` on the resulting `IntPtr`, my app crashes.

The above scenario will succeed if I use the following native code though.

```
void* qt_getenv(LPCSTR name)
{
    return LocalAlloc(0, 10);
}
```

So, it seems clear that I cannot free anything returned from managed code, unless I allocate it with `LocalAlloc`.

It is my understanding that `LocalAlloc` is Windows-specific. What about Linux/OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What about Linux

[They use malloc](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/030a3ea9b8dbeae89c90d34441d4d9a1cf4a7de6/src/pal/src/cruntime/malloc.cpp#L105)

> OSX?

[malloc_zone_malloc](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/pal/src/memory/heap.cpp#L191)

BTW, the best solution for your use case is not to use these platform-specific things compatible with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`, but instead export e.g. `void freeMemory(void* ptr)` out of your native dll/so/dylib. This way, in your native library you can use any method to allocate/free, e.g. malloc/free is the most straightforward and compatible, and it will work on all platforms. Or you can use e.g. [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) library from FreeBSD for better performance.